# Lineal functions problem; interpreting $\;{g}^{-1}(x)=g(x)$

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, contest-math, involutions

I'm preparing for a local math competition/olympiad, so I've been researching for past exams, and I've found this problem:

> Consider the lineal functions $f$ and $g$ such that $f(2)=1$,$\;g(2x)=-2f(x)\,$ and $\;{g}^{-1}(x)=g(x)$. The value of $f(2013)$ is given by:
>
> a) 2
> b) 2012
> c) 2013
> d) 2014

My first intuition was to consider $x=2$, where $$g(4)=-2f(2)=-2$$ So if I were to graph $g(x)$ (which is linear), the line would go through the point $(4,-2)$.
Now, I know I need to use the fact that $\;{g}^{-1}(x)=g(x)$, but I'm not exactly sure how to interpret it. I'm pretty sure it means that $g(x)$ and its inverse have the same output. But does this imply that $g(x)$ and  $\;{g}^{-1}(x)$ are exactly the same function? Or can they be different functions which have the same output for any $x$? Is this last case even possible in linear functions?

I've read somewhere that this is called an involution. Either way, how could I use this fact to, say, determine another point in the graph of $g(x)$, and thus, determine $g(x)$? I know this is somewhat elementary, but I'm confused.

By the way, this is my first question here, so please bear with any formatting mistakes I've made.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If two functions have the same output and the same domain, they are the same function.

You know that $g(x)=kx+n$, and that $g^{-1}(x) = g(x)=kx+n$.

Now, using the properties of inverse functions, you also know that for each $x$, you have $x = \mathrm{id}(x) = (g\circ g^{-1})(x) = (g\circ g)(x)=g(g(x))$, and this equation should give you *a lot* of information.

Comment: wow, I didn't expect an answer so quickly. Now I get it! If $x=4$ then $g(g(4))=g(-2)=4$, and $(-2,4)$ is also part of the graph. I'll work it out now, thanks for the help!